# NoReverseMatch arguments django

Tags: django, django-urls

Why does this return a NoReverseMatch error?

view:

```
def browse(request):
    thing_list = Thing.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BrowseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            make = Make.objects.all()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_makes', args=[make]))
    else:
        form = BrowseForm()
    return render(request, 'browse.html', {'form':form, 'thing_list':thing_list})

def makes(request, make):
    ad_list = Thing.objects.filter(make=make)
    return render(request, 'browse-makes.html', {'thing_list':thing_list})
```

url:

```
url(r'^browse/$', 'axlepost.views.browse.browse', name='browse'),
url(r'^browse/(?P<make>[\w-]+)/$', 'axlepost.views.browse.makes', name='browse_makes'),
```

form:

```
class BrowseForm(forms.Form):
     make = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Make.objects.all())
```

model:

```
class Make(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Thing(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make)
```

Returns `Reverse for 'browse_makes' with arguments '([<Make: Samsung>],)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`
Thanks for your ideas on how to solve this error!

Comment: Please check second line of your urls.py it should be 'axlepost.views.makes' then check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are handing `reverse()` a QuerySet rather than 1 value.  Also its an `.all()` query so it may well have multiple objects and it's not related to the form result.

```
make = Make.objects.all() # QuerySet = ([<Make: Samsung>], [<Make: Sony>], [<Make: Apple>], etc)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_makes', args=[make])) # Expects 1 value
```

Assuming you want to redirect to the `Make` selected in the form then you'll need something like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # Get the valid form data
    cd = form.cleaned_data

    # Get the selected Make
    make = cd.get('make')

    # Redirect - note 'make.make'.  You want to pass the value not the object
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_makes', kwargs={'make': make.make}))
```

Comment: Thanks. But should be `cleaned_data` not `clean_data`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are couple of issues

- Your urls does not correspond to appropriate view

change this line

```
url(r'^browse/(?P<make>[\w-]+)/$', 'axlepost.views.browse.makes', name='browse_makes'),
```

to

```
url(r'^browse/(?P<make>[\w-]+)/$', 'axlepost.views.browse', name='browse_makes'),
```

- Change your view definition to take `make` parameter

  def browse(request, make):
     ...
     #change your local variable 'make' to something else

Comment: Thanks for your response, but Im not sure that this will solve my problem. I added more information above.. I am trying to have a dropdown browse form with different `make` options, then when the user selects a make, it redirects to `browse_make`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @NickB, Is your views file is views.py and view function (`makes`) in it. Then you need to change `'axlepost.views.browse.makes'` to `'axlepost.views.makes'`.